# What color does label text and prefix icon takes(default color) if no color is specified in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

I need to know the default color for label text and prefix icon. What color will it take if no color is given specifically for labe text and prefix icon!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes the PrimarySwatch color Defined on ThemeData in MaterialApp at the beginning of your App.